# Writing a query parser in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm trying to write a parser that supports the following type of query clauses

> from: A person
>   at: a specific company
>   location: The person's location

So a sample query would be like -

```
from:Alpha at:Procter And Gamble location:US
```

How do i write this generic parser in javascript. Also, I was considering including AND operators inside queries like

```
from:Alpha AND at:Procter And Gamble AND location:US
```

However, this would conflict with the criteria value in any of the fields (Procter And Gamble)

Comment: Please include the code you have so far.

Comment: Your syntax is not very well designed. How to expect to be able to tell the different between AND as an operator, and the "and" in "Procter and Gamble"?

Comment: @torazaburo That is the dilemma i am in.. since i wish to use a boolean AND operator for combining these clauses. I tried experimenting with '+' but it also conflicts with my dataset, eg: c++

Comment: I suggest quoting values that might contain spaces, as in `"Project and Gamble"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a character like ";" instead of AND and then call theses functions:

```
var query = 'from:Alpha;at:Procter And Gamble;location:US';
var result = query.split(';').map(v => v.split(':'));
console.log(result);
```

And then you'll have an array of pairs, which array[0] = prop name and array[1] = prop value

```js
var query = 'from:Alpha;at:Procter And Gamble;location:US';
var result = query.split(';').map(v => v.split(':'));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your query will always look like this from: at: location:
You can do this:

```js
const regex = /from:\s*(.*?)\s*at:\s*(.*?)\s*location:\s*(.*)\s*/
const queryToObj = query => {
  const [,from,at,location] = regex.exec(query)
  return {from,at,location}
}
console.log(queryToObj("from:Alpha at Betaat:         Procter And Gamble location:          US"))
```

However, adding a terminator allow you to mix order and lowering some keywords:

```js
const regex = /(\w+):\s*(.*?)\s*;/g
const queryToObj = query => {
  const obj = {}
  let temp
  while(temp = regex.exec(query)){
    let [,key,value] = temp
    obj[key] = value
  }
  return obj
}
console.log(queryToObj("from:Alpha at Beta;at:Procter And Gamble;location:US;"))
console.log(queryToObj("at:Procter And Gamble;location:US;from:Alpha at Beta;"))
console.log(queryToObj("from:Alpha at Beta;"))
```